# How to highlight vertices in editor mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Assume I have a list of (around 50) vertices calculated from meshes dynamically.

I would like to highlight them in scene in editor mode, not in play mode, to see if they are in correct position.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html 
If you can do it in play mode add this to script to work in editor too.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to add an OnDrawGizmos() or OnDrawGizmosSelected() method, from there you can use Gizmos class to do the drawing  (it has the base convered with DrawWireCube or DrawWireSphere which are suitable for rendering verticies)

Or use a slightly more advanced Handles class which requires you to import UnityEditor namespace